# struts2 + spring + jpa/hibernate java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, struts2

I added all libraries required , but i have error with a method of javax.persistence:

```
oct 16, 2013 2:41:35 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Excepción enviando evento inicializado de contexto a instancia de escuchador de     
clase org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name    
'entityManagerFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB- 
 INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceUnitInfo.getSharedCacheMode()Ljavax/persistence/SharedCacheMode;
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:473)
```

here picture of lib [CLick Me](http://upload-image.net/hibernate-7207.html)

i am using eclipse for integration this frameworks...

Comment: You need to tidy up your dependencies: you have the spring library 2.5.6 on the classpath PLUS the various 3.2.4 components. Remove this 2.5.6 library. You also have various different versions of Hibernate jars. You need to tidy these up and make them consistent.

Comment: i deleted this library and run, later i have error with scheme and solution with adding lib spring-tx and spring-jdbc, and now get the same problem.

Comment: What about the Hibernate Jars? Your versions are all over the place. These should be consistent. Delete them all and try only: hibernate-core-4.1.8.Final, hibernate-entitymanager-4.1.8.Final, hibernate-jpamodelgen-1.1.1.Final, hibernate-jpa-2.0-api

Comment: Create a maven war project which does not contain any code/resource. Define the dependencies in pom and create the war. The lib folder would contain all the correct and transitive dependencies. Then you can use these libraries in your eclipse classpath. Or if you are familiar with maven just turn your project in a maven project and you can generate eclipse project files with that too.Another advantage - if you need to change version just do in pom and all your correct transitive dependencies too will be fetched. Stay away from jar hell. :-)

Comment: https://github.com/coding-idiot/Struts2-Examples/tree/master/Struts2Spring3Hibernate - here's a maven sample project